# Gitlab SMTP setting not carrying over SSL

Tags: email, ssl, smtp, gitlab

In `gitlab.rb` I set up the smtp settings, which include the following configuration

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_ssl'] = true
```

however when I examine `smtp_settings.rb` the SSL setting is not present.
How do I configure this?

Gitlab Version: GitLab 7.0.0 d1e424b

Comment: What version of GitLab are you using?

Comment: GitLab 7.0.0 d1e424b